# Function to recreate a TForm in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I need a procedure that recreates a form.

The reason being is that I have forms with many different components.  These component values (edit box text, checkbox checked or not, etc) are saved inside onhide and loaded again isnide onshow.  This makes sure all user settings are retained between runs of the program.

The problem comes when they make a change (intentionally or otherwise) that leads to problems.  I want to be able to "reset" the form back to the default settings when the application is first installed.

I can create a reset button that runs this code

```
 FormName.free;
 DeleteFile('FormNameSettings.ini');
 FormName:=TFormName.Create(Application);
 FormName.show;
```

That does what is required.  The form is closed, clears the settings file (so states are not restored when it shows again) and then recreates the form.  The form now has the original default settings.

My problem is trying to get that code into a function that I can call easily from multiple forms.

```
procedure ResetForm(form:tform;filename:string);
begin
    form.free;
    if fileexists(filename)=true then deletefile(filename);
    <what goes here to recretae the form by the passed tform?>
end;
```

Can anyone help get that ResetForm procedure working?  Latest Delphi 11.

Comment: OT: Please consider getting rid of the comparisons against `True` or `False`. It should simply be `if FileExists(filename) then ...` without the `=true`.

Comment: Since you are loading your form state from an INI file why don't you simply have another INI file that is storing this default values and then load the state from this file instead if resetting the form state is required. in fact why don't you create a backup copy of your `FormNameSettings.ini` file every time values are saved to it. This would allow you to restore the form state to last working condition without doing full reset to default state. All this can be done by making a simple mechanism that controls from which file is the state of the form loaded based on what is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return the newly created form we actually need a var parameter for the form, but that alone is not very elegant, because one cannot pass a derived form class to a var parameter of type TForm and has to do a hard cast to please the compiler. Even using a function that returns a TForm is not much better as the result is most likely assigned to a variable of a derived form class and that would also be rejected by the compiler.

Thanks to generics we can write some code that overcomes these restrictions. As standalone generic procedures or functions are not supported in Delphi, we wrap it inside a record declaration:

```
type
  TFormUtils = record
  public
    class procedure ResetForm<T: TForm>(var form: T; const filename: string); static;
  end;
```

We also need to save some information about the form for later use:

- the owner of the form
- is the form currently showing

This allows to recreate the form.

```
class procedure TFormUtils.ResetForm<T>(var form: T; const filename: string);
begin
  var formOwner := form.Owner;
  var formShowing := form.Showing;
  form.free;
  if fileexists(filename) then
    deletefile(filename);
  form := T.Create(formOwner);
  if formShowing then
    form.Show;
end;
```

Comment: To use this function the form name must be passed like this      ResetForm(TForm(MyFormName),'Settings.ini');

Comment: Indeed. Let me find a cleaner solution...